# php datetime diff error parameter1 considered as null

Tags: php, datetime, diff

I want to get the difference (dateInterval) between 2 dateTime.
Those 2 dateTimes come from a table of my mysql database, which contains 2 columns, which are varchar strings, because of json format, example :

```
{"name":"firstdate","date":"2016-06-06 23:42:35","id":"1"}
```

but those columns can be null.

So I've an array which store those 2 columns, as exemple :

```
$array[0] and $array[1] which may contains null or the json
```

in a script I check if the content of the $array[$i] is null or not, if it's not null, I use json_decode, true on the $array[$i].

Then with

```
$dateNow = new DateTime("now", new dateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
```

and

```
$array[$i]['date'] = new DateTime($jsonDecoded['date'], new dateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
```

I do :

```
if($dateNow < $array[$i]['date'])
{
    $diffDate = $array[$i]['date']->diff($dateNow);
}
```

I get this error :

```
PHP message: PHP Warning:  DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, null given
```

By the way I've checked with a var_dump the content of $array[$i]['date'] and it's not null, it contains the date in the right format.
Moreover, even if I write a date by myself instead of using the json decoded, it still returns the same error...

Comment: What if you change $dateNow = new DateTime("now", new dateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')); just to $dateNow = new DateTime();

Comment: I've already tried this, but the same error occurs...

Comment: Please provide full code block

Comment: I had added in my code : `global $dateNow;` after the creation of the $dateNow variable. I've removed it, and everything works now...
I'm really sorry, and both confused.